# Flutter: Internal Storage File could not delete

Tags: flutter, file, android-permissions, internal-storage

I am trying to delete internal storage file into Flutter(Android). But It show error like this

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot delete file, path =
> '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image Description (1).jpg' (OS Error: No
> such file or directory, errno = 2)

And I also check exitance of the file before deleting. Here is my code to delete file.

```
await Future.forEach(_selectedFile, (element) async {
      if (await element?.exists() ?? false) {
        await element?.delete();  // I got error in this line
      }
    });
```

I added all required permission to read and write internal storage.

Anyone have idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet:

```js
Future<void> deleteFile(File file) async {
  try {
    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Error in getting access to the file.
  }
}
```

Comment: my concern is that why file has not deleted even it exits? any idea about that?

Comment: Could you please update and share more source code about it so that I can take a better look at it

Comment: this is the only code where I get error.